# socket: operation not permitted when connecting to cloudsql

Tags: postgresql, sockets, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql

When trying to connect with the following settings I get a `socket:operation not permitted` error on app engine, but not locally when using cloud-sql-proxy. The following code works locally but not with app engine:

```
connString = "user=USER_NAME password=PASSWORD host=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_NAME dbname=DB_NAME"
DBCon, err2 = sql.Open("postgres", connString)
```

Both the app engine and cloud sql are in the same project. Does anyone have any insight on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

My App Engine projects use MySQL, but connections should theoretically be the same. Here is how I connect. Let me know if this doesn't work with Postgres

**EDIT for 2nd gen instances**

```
connString:= "@unix(/cloudsql/<your instance>)"
if appengine.IsDevAppServer() {
    connString = "@tcp(<instance ip>:port)"
}
sqlUser := "<your user>"
sqlPass := "<your pass>"
connString = sqlUser + ":" + sqlPass + connString

// connect main db
db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", connString)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

**Old string for 1st gen:**
`connString := "@cloudsql(<your instance>)"`

Comment: app engine standard seems to say to use a socket for postgres https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine

Comment: With the 2nd gen instances they released some time ago, the connection string is different. Now it's "@unix(/cloudsql/<your instance name>)". Updating answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Cloud SQL+postgres is not supported on AppEngine standard yet:

"Note: Connection from an App Engine standard environment application to a PostgreSQL instance is not supported"

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine

Comment: I think it's allowed now.

Answer (score 0):

`NOTE: This is for mysql second version db`

main.go

```
import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql",
    "database/sql"
)

func InitDB() (err error, db *DB) {
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", os.Getenv("SQL_STRING"))
}
```

`SQL_STRING: 'username:password@cloudsql(project:region:instance_id)/db'`

For more ref https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/cloud-sql/reference